# Proof of implicit function theorem for a complex function not necessarily holomorphic

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

> Let $U,V\subset\mathbb{C}$ be domains, and $F(z,w):U\times V\to\mathbb{C}$ be continuous, and holomorphic in $z$ for every  fixed $w\in V$. Let $(z_0,w_0)\in U\times V$ be s.t $F(z_0,w_0)=0$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(z_0,w_0)=F_1(z_0,w_0)\neq0$. Let $r>0$ be s.t for every $z_0\neq z\in\overline{\mathbb{D}_r(z_0)}, F(z,w_0)\neq0$. Prove that there exists $\delta>0$ s.t for every $w\in\mathbb{D}_\delta(w_0)$ there exists a unique $z=g(w)\in\overline{\mathbb{D}_r(z_0)}$ s.t $F(z,w)=0$.

Edit:
I now see that I cannot use the implicit function theorem for real functions as $F$ is not necessarily continuiously differentiable as a real function. I tried using the argument theorem but this didnt get me too far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will need some assumption on the regularity of $F$ with respect to the second variable. The real version of the implicit function theorem includes a uniqueness result, so that should not be an issue. Am I overlooking something here?

Comment: @Thomas What do you mean regulariry of $F$ wrt to the second variable? Also, it seems youre correct and its given that $z$ is unique.

Comment: To apply the (real)  implicit function theorem, $F$ must be continuously differentiable as a function of it's real variables, in your case as a map from $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Thomas I see. I now realize I cant use the theorem here. Do you have any idea how I can go about it?

Comment: @GBA I may be missing something... But unicity is also an element of the conclusion of [Implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem).

Comment: As stated this isn't true, e.g., $F(z, 0) = z$ and $F(z, w) = 1$ for $w \neq 0$, and $(z_0,w_0)=(0,0)$. Is $F$ continuous, or holomorphic in each variable separately, or ... something?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Sorry, I added that $F$ is continuous (and as was stated, holomorphic in the first variable).

Comment: I'd start by showing the function $$\eta(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_r}\frac{F_1(z,w)\,dz}{F(z,w)}$$is continuous and for each $w$ in $D_\delta(w_0)$ counts the number of zeros in the disk $D_r(z_0)$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang This is simply the argument principle right?

Comment: Yes; continuity can be deduced from the Cauchy integral formula as shown by mathcounterexamples.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $z \in \mathbb C$ and $b \gt 0$, let $C_b(z)$ be the circle centered on $z$ of radius $b$ and $D_b(z)$ the associated open disk.

**Let's first prove that it exists $r_1,r_2 \gt 0$ such that $F$ doesn't vanish on $C_{r_1}(z_0) \times D_{r_2}(w_0)$**

Let $a = \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(z_0,w_0)= F_1(z_0,w_0) \neq 0$. As $F(\cdot, w_0)$ is supposed to be holomorphic, from $F(z_0,w_0) = 0$ and $a \neq 0$, it follows that it exists $r_1 \gt 0$ such that $F(z,w_0) \neq 0$ in $\overline{D_{r_1}(z_0)} \setminus \{z_0\}$. As $C_{r_1}(z_0)$ is compact, $\lvert F \rvert$ attains a positive minimum $b$ on $C_{r_1}(z_0)$. From the continuity of $F$ on $U \times V$ and again the compactness of $C_{r_1}(z_0)$, we can find $r_2 \gt 0$ such that $\lvert F(z,w) \rvert \gt b/2 \gt 0$ for $(z,w) \in C_{r_1}(z_0) \times D_{r_2}(w_0)$.

**About the desired result**

From the formula

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(z,w) = \frac{1}{2 i \pi} \int_{C_{\delta}(z_0)} \frac{F(\zeta,w)}{(\zeta -z)^2} \ d\zeta$$ which holds for $\delta \gt 0$ small enough, $z \in D_\delta(z_0)$  and the continuity of $F$, it follows that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(z,w)$ is also continuous. Therefore the map
$$\eta(w)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C_{r_1}(z_0)}\frac{F_1(z,w)\,dz}{F(z,w)}
$$ is well defined and continuous in the open disk $D_{r_2}(w_0)$. According to the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle), $\eta(w)$ is the number of zeros of the equation $F(z,w)=0$ in the open disk $D_{r_1}(z_0)$. Also $\eta(w_0) = 1$ as $z_0$ is the only root of $F(z,w_0) = 0$ in $D_{r_1}(z_0)$. We finally get the desired conclusion that for any $w \in D_{r_2}(w_0)$, the equation $F(z,w) = 0$ has a unique solution in the open disk $D_{r_1}(z_0)$.